# How to simulate these criteria in R

Tags: r, simulation

I want to create two columns, labelled as Group and Size. The Group has letters A to E. The Size column has a range of 10 to 100.

I want to produce 300 samples and getting the following data for the Group based on Size:

```
E= Sizes less than 20
D=  Sizes of an SD +/- of the mean Size
C= Sizes between 40-59
B= Sizes between 60-79
A=Sizes greater than 79
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data, e.g. with `dput`?

Comment: Obviously, I don't have sample data as I want to create sample data using the criteria mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is

```
sampleSizes <- sample(10:100,300,replace = TRUE)
groups <- rep("No group",length(sampleSizes))

#criteria E
groups[sampleSizes < 20] <- "E"
#criteria D
meanSize <- mean(sampleSizes)
SD <- sd(sampleSizes)
groups[sampleSizes >= meanSize-SD & sampleSizes <= meanSize+SD] <- "D"
#criteria C
groups[sampleSizes >= 40 & sampleSizes <= 59] <- "C"
#criteria B
groups[sampleSizes >= 60 & sampleSizes <= 79] <- "B"
#criteria A
groups[sampleSizes > 79] <- "A"
groups
```

what you want?

To get your desired two columns, just put them next to each other in a data.frame like

```
result <- data.frame(Sizes = sampleSizes, Group = groups)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am sorry but it does not reflect my question. I need to columns Group  and Size, but I get only one column of the letters, which does not make sense for me. Group B is lacking